# Using hiredis (redis client library)

Tags: redis, hiredis

I have the redis server installed, and can use it from the command line. Now, I am wanting to write a client program using hiredis. To begin with, I tried to compile example.c which is present in the hiredis directory:

```
vishal@expmach:~/redis-2.6.14/deps/hiredis$ ls

adapters  async.h       COPYING  dict.h        *example.c*        example-libevent.c      
hiredis.c  Makefile  net.h      sds.c  test.c async.c   CHANGELOG.md  dict.c   example-
ae.c  example-libev.c  fmacros.h           hiredis.h  net.c     README.md  sds.h
```

Here are the commands:

```
vishal@expmach:~/redis-2.6.14/deps/hiredis$ gcc -c -I hiredis example.c
vishal@expmach:~/redis-2.6.14/deps/hiredis$ gcc -o example -I hiredis -L hiredis -lhiredis -lm
```

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhiredis
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am not sure how to go about fixing this. Please help.

Comment: Try this :     `sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" > sudo /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf`   &  `sudo ldconfig`. Then compile the example.c like this : `gcc example.c -o example -l hiredis -I /usr/local/include/hiredis/`

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -o example example.c -lhiredis $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you juste juste the provided Makefile?

> make
>
> ./hiredis-example

Comment: Thanks! My plan is to use hiredis client library in some existing code. So I need to know how to compile it using gcc.

Comment: I am still learning how to understand Makefiles. Can you please tell me how I could go about using gcc to begin with.

Comment: you need to build the lib first and then gcc -o hiredis-example   example.o libhiredis.a will work. If you type make, you will see all the commands issued to build the example

Comment: This works if I have example.c and libhiredis.a in the same directory. But when I have example.c in a different directory, then I get and error saying "gcc: libhiredis.a: No such file or directory"

Comment: just look at any gcc tutorial, and you will get it very quickly. Good luck!